# Spring Cloud Kubernetes FeignClient Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am using spring cloud kubernetes with spring boot and necessary RBAC requirements needed for the project.

```
<!-- kubernetes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have 2 microservices running in kubernetes

1. `my-service`
2. `some-service`

The `my-service` is running with spring boot 2.x and `some-service` is running with Spring boot 1.x. Both the services are exposed via the Kubernetes `Service` and with proper endpoints.

excerpt of `application.yaml` for `my-service` is as below.

```
some-service:
      url: http://some-service:8080
      serviceName: some-service
```

And the FeignClient used is as below.

```
//FeignClient(url = "${some-service.url}") // does not work either
@FeignClient(value = "${some-service.serviceName}")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public interface SomeServiceClient {
```

Also I have made `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=false`

With this in place I expect that `my-service` should be able to talk to `some-service` via kubernetes service discovery But I get this error.

```
ERROR c.b.d.m.s.c.MatchCoordinator - error=FeignException: status 404 reading SomeServiceClient#get(Test
ion,Output) stacktrace=feign.FeignException: status 404 reading SomeServiceClient#get
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. Also I do not have the spring.application.name set for `some-service` since its a third party service.

Can someone please help. Also FYI that the services work properly with port-forwarding and if accessed via Ingress.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789632/feign-client-not-able-to-make-calls-kubernetes
Having similar problem

Comment: My issue was the JWT propagation not working with spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found that the discrepancy was at the `some-service` where the payload of was updated and `my-service` FeignClient was not updated. and hence caused the HTTP 404 Error. However it works now with the `FeignClient` properly and able to do a service discovery with the service name properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a name set for some-service, and it's a 3rd party service, I think the better approach would be to call it via RestTemplate or something.

Feign client needs to have the service name configured and known, for it to call that particular service in the network using service discovery.

Comment: this  may be another approach , However my current approached worked well. ! Thank you!